# calculate only when certain cells are changed

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I did some searching on google and cannot find the answer, if it's achievable.

Is there a way to have Excel ONLY calculate if the cells (for example) A2:Z300 are changed/updated in any way
calculate=automatic
And every other cell in the sheet
calculate=manual

Can be VBA.
Appreciate any tips on this

Comment: Turn Calculation to `Manual` on excel (or use a `workbook open` event to do this) and then use a `worksheet change` event to determine when to calculate the sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your calculation to manual:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

And add a worksheet change event on your desired worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)
    'Checks whether the changed range has an intersection within your desired range:'
    Set isect = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A2:Z3000"))        

    If Not isect is Nothing then 'ie, there is an intersection, call the calculation.
        Application.Calculate
    End If
End Sub
```

Bear in mind, though, that your sub will run whenever there is **any** change within your worksheet.